# How to get unique message id from email message using office 365 API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft graph 
REST API I am using follwing URl for fetching email messages from inbox and I am storing them in mysql database

I am using id  "id": "AAMkADczNjA0MTM3LTQ1YmU....
as unique identifyer but I see that this is not unique one because in my database there are same ids for different message. so where will I find unique message id for email.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages

Answer (score 1):

Unique in what scope?  A given mailbox, or across mailboxes?

Comment: message id for given mailbox. if i have 1000 emails in my inbox i see that message id is not unique and same message id can be there for two different email messages.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible.  The Exchange store would have all sorts of problems if there were two messages in the same mailbox with the exact same id.  Typically when I have thought 2 ids are the same, on closer inspection I see that there is one character that is different.  We are talking about the ItemId (the primary id) here, right?  Not something like the internet Message id?

Comment: Yes  ItemId (the primary id). So is there any unique identifier for message

Comment: The id returned by EWS/REST makes the id unique *across* mailboxes because we embed the mailbox identity into the id along with the entryId and a few nuts and bolts.  *However*, the ItemId is based on the PR_ENTRYID which means that when the item moves from folder to folder (or mailbox to mailbox), the id will change.  Also, the Exchange store does not reuse entry ids.  So, the ItemId for a given item is unique, but not immutable...

Comment: David, this aligns with my experience. The message ID of a given message may change over time, thus it cannot be used to do the one thing you'd think an ID is good for, referencing. Which to be polite, is a little unusual.

Comment: @dearsina - Indeed :)  It would be nice if Exchange came up with an id format that is immutable, at least within the scope of a mailbox.  In fact, they could even call it the "immutable id" or something.  We will see.

Comment: @DavidSterling-MSFT How do you suggest I go about it? So far, the only solution I can think about is to hash the message body and time sent _along with_ with the ID to at least make it very, very improbable that two messages have the same ID. But that seems clunky to say the least.

Comment: Try adding this to your request from now on:  Prefer: IdType=”ImmutableId”

Answer (score 1):

Message Ids may look same but actually, they are not same. Some characters are different.

```
AQMkADAwAT...XFR0AAAA0DckhAAAA
AQMkADAwAT...XFR0AAAA0DckeAAAA
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL string comparisons aren't case sensitive by default so that may be what's catching you out.
To check the case of the *id* as well use BINARY e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY `message_id` = "AAMkADczNjA0MTM3LTQ1YmU...
```

Comment: (Where one of the strings involved is fixed (e.g., a literal), I'd decorate that. How about explicitly specifying COLLATION?)